# Which is the better magnetic arrangement for a voice coil to give a larger amplitude of movement all else being equal?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnets, acoustics

Given everything else equal (e.g. same overall amount of magnetic material, same strength magnetic material, same coil, same power supplied, etc. etc.) which of these two magnetic configurations of a voice coil actuator would produce higher amplitude sound from the speaker cone?

I assume 1 should be better than 2 (and even that 2 shouldnt really work at all), but my colleague is claiming no 2 works better!

P.S. The non-magnetic filler material is just a sliver to keep the two magnets stuck together

EDIT: Apparently there is an effect which has been described before - there's a [question here about it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150033/how-does-this-simple-electric-train-work). In this case I suppose my question becomes - why aren't voice coils made using 2 opposing magnets like this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the source of these two diagrams? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson This isn't homework, I'm 38. I drew the diagrams on MS PPT.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It seems obvious to me that two opposing magnets are just going to cancel each other out in a voice coil - but my colleague, a test engineer working on this, is claiming that is working better, creating higher amplitude oscillation. I want to say that's impossible, and that there's something wrong with his experimental setup, but I'm not an expert on magnetism, and am wondering if there is a way this could happen?

Comment: @OliverWalters it heavily depends on the particular arrangement of coil to magnet Sure the way you have drawn it seems to do so. But the magnetic field isn't entirely constant and once in motion you have bigger grip area... But yeah

Comment: @joojaa 'the way you have drawn it seems to do so' - to do what? Also what do you mean by 'once in motion you have bigger grip area...'? Cheers

Comment: you have drawn it as symmetrical, if it isnt entirely symmetrical then what happens.